# How do you separate Handling charge from shipping?

Tags: expresso-store

We'd like to use the default handling charge as part of Store but in a different way.  We are adding a handling charge to each item but we want it to be separate from shipping and also allow us to rename it on the front end from Handling to whatever we'd like.  The handling charge is actually a Ticketing Fee and on our end having it show up as handling charge is fine we just would like it separate from Shipping and still show shipping as $0 on the front end since we don't ship some products.

Answer (score 1):

In the Store checkout tag there is an `{order_handling}` variable which will display the handling total.

There is also `{order_shipping_ex_handling}` if you want to display the shipping amount excluding handling.

Both of these can be combined with `_inc_tax` to display the tax inclusive price: `{order_handling_inc_tax}`, or `_val` to display the unformatted number: `{order_handling_val}`.